# Symfony asset component "" is not a valid URL

Tags: php, symfony, assets, webpack-dev-server, symfony-2.7

I am using webpack dev server to serve my assets in local development. I have following in my paramters.yml.dist

```
# local assets devserver address
# if you want to use webpack dev server use "http://localhost:8090"
# and then > npm run devserver
assets_base_url: ~
```

I have following in framework for local environment.

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_urls: ["%assets_base_url%"]
```

My problem is that it is not working with base settings of "~" for my colleagues that are not using devserver.

```
Error: "" is not a valid URL
```

What should I do enable or disable devserver assets url by one setting in parameters.yml

[Symfony docs for asset component](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of put `base_urls: ["%assets_base_url%"]`, you can do that in the Extension Class of your bundle.

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AcmeHelloExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    // ...

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $assetBaseUrl = $container->getParameter('assets_base_url');
        if (!$assetBaseUrl) {
            $container->prependExtensionConfig(
                'framework',
                array(
                    'assets' => array(
                        'base_urls' => array($assetBaseUrl)
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `PrependExtensionInterface::prepend()` method you can prepends settings over `config.yml` configuration.

Comment: How it will work if I want to use this setting globally and I have 20+ company bundles in project.

Comment: You need a 21° bundle where to do this (call it "CoreBundle", or whatever), and the others bundle must be now have a dependency to this new bundle.

Comment: I will show this solution or I will force all colleagues to set it manually  to correct Url. Rather then creating dependencies like this.

Comment: wait, wait, wait... I maybe was looking for the most complicated solution

Comment: try to change `assets_base_url: ~` to `assets_base_url: []`

Comment: it gives me assets_base_url: {  } in parameters.yml and error on build :(

Comment: yeah, you also need to change `base_urls: ["%assets_base_url%"]` to `base_urls: "%assets_base_url%"`